# Continuously scroll text in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of any jQuery plugins that can achieve the scrolling effect like the one seen [here](http://www.nwfencingco.com)?

I'm not too well-up on javascript or jQuery and want to find something simple that just works. I've found examples on the net that I either can't understand or plugins that don't work. Don't need any fancy effects, just literally the ability to scroll the contents of a div and pause on mouse over, resume on mouse exit.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to add, this is using ASP.NET MVC3. Everything I try seems to be incompatible.

Comment: I found one issue that JQuery seems to break alongside Prototype, so I switched to a JQuery lightbox plugin and then I could get rid of the NoConflict setting and use a JQuery news ticker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removal of Lightbox using Prototype got my JQuery stuff working ok.

Answer (score 3):

You can visit this url 
[Click here for find it](http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/)

modify this and hope it work fine.. 
you just decrease its pause time it will work as you specify in example.

Answer (score 2):

Search for a jquery news ticker ? Here's a tutorial for how to achieve this effect : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-simple-jquery-news-ticker/

**I've put together a fiddle test page : http://jsfiddle.net/CzqFL/**

It works the way you want, smooth scrolling as the site you were talking about in your first post..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this and at first it would not work. I'm using ASP.NET MVC3. I had to use jQuery.noConflict() to get a lightbox plugin to work and unless I take this line out, your sample won't work. When I got it working, it's really jerky every few seconds, jerks a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but just in case anyone comes by you can achieve this news ticker effect with this small function:

```
    function tick() {
        jQuery('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function () {
            jQuery(this).appendTo(jQuery('#ticker')).slideDown();
        });
    }
```

And then setting an interval to execute it every period of time you choose:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        tick()
    }, 5000);
```

**I've put together a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XbjYS/1/**